# Hide Link When its Href is the Current Page - CSS Only

Tags: html, css

In a `<ul/>` I need to hide one of the `<li/>s` if the `<li/>`'s `href` is the current page.  I found a couple of postings on `SO`, but they're not helpful to me.  The item with class = *hideMeWhenActive* needs to be hidden when its `href` is active.  No `javascript`, just `CSS`.  Is it possible?  If so, how?

```
<ul class="primaryNav">
    <li><a href="/Coverage/CoverageSummary/" class="primaryNav__link">Coverage</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Claim/ClaimList/" class="primaryNav__link">Claims</a></li>
    <li><a href="/HelpCenter/Main" class="primaryNav__link">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/IdCard/" class="btn hideMeWhenActive">Card</a></li> /*THIS ONE NEEDS TO BE HIDDEN*/
 </ul>
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter, what can I do to improve the question?  I think it's within SO guidelines and spent a lot of time researching before composing the post.  Help me help myself.

Comment: As far as I know, CSS can't access the current uri, so CSS can't possibly know which which one is active. I'm sorry, you'll need javascript to add or remove `active` from the classList. From there, it's easy to make the CSS hide the active object.

Comment: @ShamPooSham...Possible or not is part of my question.  I don't know enough about CSS, that's why I'm asking this.  I'm trying to learn more.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Indeed, CSS can't detect **anything**. It can only style based on the ruleset given and there is not such property as "current page". You need javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D...so, with javascript, I need to add a class or something to the item and then have css do it's thing?  At that point, I'm probably better off using javascript for the whole thing.

Comment: @BigDaddy _Possible or not is part of my question._ It sure is. It's **not** possible with just CSS. As others have suggested, you will need to use JS or something to detect the URL to compare against.

Comment: @SamuelLiew...but then I'll need to use javascript, right?  Any CSS only solution?

Answer (score -1):

Check this code, if can be useful for you, if I understood your question.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".primaryNav_link" ).click(function(){
    $(".hideMeWhenActive").addClass("showMeWhenActive").removeClass("hideMeWhenActive");
    $(this).parent().addClass("hideMeWhenActive").removeClass("showMeWhenActive");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin-left: 0;
   padding-left: 1em;
   text-indent: -1em;
}
.hideMeWhenActive {
  display: none;
}
.showMeWhenActive {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="primaryNav">
  <li>- <a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Coverage</a></li>
  <li>- <a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Claims</a></li>
  <li>- <a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Help</a></li>
  <li class="hideMeWhenActive">- <a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Card</a></li> <!--THIS ONE NEEDS TO BE HIDDEN-->
</ul>
```

it just hides the active link.

**Edit #1 (only CSS):**

```css
ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin-left: 0;
   padding-left: 1em;
   text-indent: -1em;
}
.primaryNav_link {
  display: block;
}
.primaryNav_link:focus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="primaryNav">
  <li><a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Coverage</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Claims</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Help</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="primaryNav_link">Card</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm conflicted. It's a good answer, so that deserves an upvote, but it completely contradicts what the OP asked for, so....

Comment: @YaakovAinspan answers should be voted on based upon their usefulness within the context of the question. If this doesn't answer the question, then, it's not useful.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, it's a helpful alternative.

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, I don't think this is attainable by using purely CSS.

You can definitely make a CSS class with a `display: none` attribute, but to trigger that class to be added on the `li` element only when that button is clicked, you will need to add some JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Please support your answer with functional code that either illustrates what you're saying or helps OP

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer to the question that was actually asked. It doesn't deserve so many downvotes.

Comment: @thirtydot...I agree